# Not able to load a resource from the resources test folder

Tags: java, maven, junit, intellij-idea, resources

I'm trying with this simple test:

```
@Test
public void testResourceExist() {
    URL file = getClass().getResource("sample.htm");

    Assert.assertNotNull(file);
}
```

My directory structure is:

```
src
  - main
      - java
      - resources
  - test
      - java
          ResourcesTest.java
      - resources
          sample.htm
```

I'm using IntelliJ Idea and maven and even the Ide autocompletes the sample.htm file.
If i check the test-classes folder i can see the sample.htm file there.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to add a slash before the resource name.

"/sample.htm" instead of "sample.htm" and its working

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you shouldn't be reading this as a file resource, but as a classpath resource. All files in `resources` are packaged as part of your jar, not placed directly on the filesystem, and all class paths are absolute, so you don't need a slash at the start. Rather, the error you have here is that you're trying to read a file resource, using `getResource()`, rather than a classpath resource, using `getClasspathResourceAsStream()` or something similar. If you use the latter then you'll not need the slash.

Comment: Is this a better approach? getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName); it's working without the slash but i'm not sure if this is loading the file from the classpath. I'm so newbie with java...

Comment: It's a much better approach. You should always try to avoid reading things from the file system, because you've no idea where your app will be deployed and in some environments your app may be denied file access, or the paths may change, or the files may have been moved. If everything is wrapped up nice and tidy in the jar/war then you will always know where your resources are.